# Socket Connection Always Null When Connecting To Remote Server

Tags: android, sockets, server

Good day.Im trying to connect to server with socket.Here is my code on how i do it.

```
 private class SocketConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            connect();
            try {
                 out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.append("error").append("socketcoonection").println();
            }

            String msg = null;
            try {
                msg = in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (run) {
                System.out.append(msg).append("socketcoonection").println();
                out.println();
                out.flush();
                        /*try {
                            msg = in.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }*/
            }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is the connect() method

```
 public void connect() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("vaenterprises.org/test.php", 8080);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            run = true;
        }
    }
```

and this is the server side php code of `test.php`

```
echo json_encode("socket working");
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
```

and the address link is vaenterprises.org/test/php so im trying to connect to it and read the input or output stream or the echo.Whatever i do,i get nullPointerException at  `System.out.append(msg).append("socketcoonection").println();` and during debug i figured out that its socket which is null...Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 'new Socket("vaenterprises.org/test.php", 8080);'. That will not do. If you want to connect to a server using the Socket class it should be 'new Socket("vaenterprises.org", 8080);'. But then if you want to access a php file after that you are out of luck. Why not use http to access a php file on web?

Comment: Your connect method is void. Make the return value boolean and do not continue if you cannot connect.

Comment: Ok dear greenapps im making a chat applicaiton and for 2 users to be able to chat NORMALLY without idiotic each 2 seconds http request for new messages i want to open a socket and listen on server side changes for new messages to appear...thats the idea:(